# Using rspec and factory_girl, where to store hard coded values that need to be shared?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am using rspec and factory_girl in a rails 3 app.

I am setting up my factories in /spec/factories right now, and just curious where I should place attribute-hashes or hard-coded ID's that other factories will need to reference?

I'm new to this so looking for guidance on how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Factory Girl is expecting that you use associations and sequences, not hard coded id's. the following examples give you the core of what to search for in the rdoc and basics for using the factories. You should probably stay away from any hard coded id's because it will lead to brittle tests that don't work on some random occasion (which takes you half a day to get to the bottom of).

```
#the basics
Factory.define(:post) do |f|
  f.association :author
end

Factory.define(:comment) do |f|
  f.text "boo"
end

# callbacks
Factory.define :article_with_comment, :parent => :article do |article|
  article.after_create { |a| Factory(:comment, :article => a) }
end

p = Factory(:article_with_comment)
p.comments.first.text # => "boo"
p.author #=> yep, used the association to make it

#sequences
Factory.define(:author) do |f|
  f.email { Factory.next(:email) }
end

# and override the default behavior
p = Factory(:post, :title => 'new post', :author => Factory(:author, :email => "me@me.com") )
p.author.email # => me@me.com

...deep inside a test

p = Post.find_by_title('new post') # => this is the most basic way to get around id's
```

some more nice info here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/254496652/aint-no-calla-back-girl